# How do I ignore a subtring in a string when looking for a file?

Tags: c#

How do I ignore a subtring in a string when looking for a file?

The file pattern can be:-

```
180814_1535_Original_001_2A1992.pdf
date_time_FileType_Code_UserCode.pdf
```

I am already able to search to the path directory and locate the file if all the value required is given in the parameter, but the time will not be given. How do i search the file name but ignore the time?

Parts of my code is as below:

```
if (reportType == 1)
        {
            reportPath = reportPath + String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}", reportDate) + "\\" + String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}", reportDate) + "%" + "_" + "Original" + clientCode + ".pdf";

        };
```

I already define the path directory in the reportPath.

Comment: Get all the files that match a basic filter using `GetFiles` and then do a more refined filter using a loop or a LINQ query.

Comment: You could use `.StartsWith()` passing the date format and then `.Contains()`, passing the client code. No idea if *Original* matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know part of the file name, you can just do a search and replace the part you don't know with `*` (which represents any number of missing characters) or a series of `?` marks (one per character, if you know the length), like so:

```
if (reportType == 1)
{
    var fileMask = String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}_????_Original_etc.pdf", date);
    var path = Directory.GetFiles(reportPath, fileMask)[0];
};
```

In case of duplicates you can sort with a bit of LINQ to get the most recent file:

```
var fileMask = String.Format("{0:yyMMdd}_????_Original_etc.pdf", date);
var paths = Directory.GetFiles(reportPath, fileMask);
var path = paths.OrderByDescending( p => p ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It doesn't works, the series of ? marks shows the ? in the variable. The filemask will be 180814_????_Original_2A1991.pdf

Comment: Correct. It's an old-fashioned DOS wildcard. That is why there is a call to `Directory.GetFiles(string,string)` and the `[0]` afterwards to get the first hit.

Comment: My apology, it works. I pointed it to a wrong folder before. 1 question for this solution: If i have 2 files with the same name but different creation time, how do i select the latest creation time?

Comment: See second example just added.